# Sigmoid function

Tags: logistic-regression

How did we arrive at the sigmoid function for calculating probabilities?

Why not use some other function that " squashes " the values to lie between [0, 1]. Maybe even just normalise the values so they all add up to one.

Comment: The derivative of this function is nice, making it invaluable for gradient descent.

Comment: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/162988/why-sigmoid-function-instead-of-anything-else

Comment: This question starts with a false premise. Many people use other linking functions. Logit is the most popular, but [probit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probit) is very popular as well.

Answer (score 3):

I think a really nice explanation for the popularity of the sigmoid function is in these lecture notes (http://www.stat.cmu.edu/~cshalizi/uADA/12/lectures/ch12.pdf)

1. The most obvious idea is to let $p(x)$ be a linear function of $x$. Every increment
   of a component of $x$ would add or subtract so much to the probability. The
   conceptual problem here is that $p$ must be between $0$ and $1$, and linear functions
   are unbounded. Moreover, in many situations we empirically see “diminishing
   returns” — changing $p$ by the same amount requires a bigger change in
   $x$ when $p$ is already large (or small) than when $p$ is close to $1/2$. Linear models
   can’t do this.
2. The next most obvious idea is to let $\log p(x)$ be a linear function of $x$, so that
   changing an input variable multiplies the probability by a fixed amount. The
   problem is that logarithms are unbounded in only one direction, and linear
   functions are not.
3. Finally, the easiest modification of $\log p$ which has an unbounded range is the
   logistic (or logit) transformation, $\log (p(1−p))$
   . We can make this a linear function
   of $x$ without fear of nonsensical results. (Of course the results could still
   happen to be wrong, but they’re not guaranteed to be wrong.)

Comment: > The problem is that logarithms are unbounded in only one direction, and linear functions are not.
Aren't logarithms actually unbounded in both directions?